# How do Convolutional neural networks proceed after the pooling step?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to learn about convolutional neural networks, but i am having trouble understanding what happens to neural networks after the pooling step.

[image]

So starting from the left we have our 28x28 matrix representing our picture. We apply a three 5x5 filters to it to get three 24x24 feature maps. We then apply max pooling to each 2x2 square feature map to get three 12x12 pooled layers. I understand everything up to this step.

But what happens now? The document I am reading says:

> "The final layer of connections in the network is a fully-connected
>   layer. That is, this layer connects every neuron from the max-pooled
>   layer to every one of the 10 output neurons. "

The text did not go further into describing what happens beyond that and it left me with a few questions.

How are the three pooled  layers mapped to the 10 output neurons? By fully connected, does it mean each neuron in every one of the three layers of the 12x12 pooled layers has a weight connecting it to the output layer?  So there are 3x12x12x10 weights linking from the pooled layer to the output layer? Is an activation function still taken at the output neuron?

*Pictures and extract taken from this online resource: http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap6.html*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the fully connected layer provides the main way for the neural network to make a prediction. If you have ten classes, then a fully connected layer consists of ten neurons, each with a different probability as to the likelihood of the classified sample belonging to that class (each neuron represents a class). These probabilities are determined by the hidden layers and convolution. The pooling layer is simply outputted into these ten neurons, providing the final interface for your network to make the prediction. Here's an example. After pooling, your fully connected layer could display this:

(0.1)

(0.01)

(0.2)

(0.9)

(0.2)

(0.1)

(0.1)

(0.1)

(0.1)

(0.1)

Where each neuron contains a probability that the sample belongs to that class. In this, case, if you are classifying images of handwritten digits and each neuron corresponds to a prediction that the image is 1-10, then the prediction would be 4. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're on the right track. There is a layer with a weight matrix of 4320 entries.

This matrix will be typically arranged as 432x10. This is because these 432 number are **a fixed-size representation** of the input image. At this point, you don't care about how you got it -- CNN, plain feed-forward or a crazy RNN going pixel-by-pixel, you just want to turn the description into classifaction. In most toolkits (e.g. `TensorFlow`, `PyTorch` or even plain `numpy`), you'll need to explicitly reshape the 3x12x12 output of the pooling into a 432-long vector. But that's just a rearrangement, the individual elements do not change.

Additionally, there will usually be **a 10-long vector of biases**, one for every output element.

Finally **about the nonlinearity**: Since this is about classification, you typically want the output 10 units to represent posterior probabilities that the input belongs to a particular class (digit). For this purpose, the [softmax function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) is used: `y = exp(o) / sum(exp(o))`, where `exp(o)` stands for an element-wise exponentiation. It guarantees that it's output will be a proper categorical distribution, all elements in <0; 1> and summing up to 1. There is a nice a detailed discussion of softmax in neural networks in the [Deep Learning book](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html) (I recommend reading Section 6.2.1 in addition to the softmax Sub-subsection itself.)

Also note that this is not specific to convolutional networks at all, you'll find this block  `fully connected layer` -- `softmax` at the end of virtually **every classification network**. You can also view this block as the actual classifier, while anything in front of it (a shallow CNN in your case) is just trying to prepare nice features.